# What's mean the MonitorRequestWrapper and why am I not getting parameters from request?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I am working in Netbeans IDE and i have wrote JS-code for sending HTTP Request to server:

```
function applyFilter(){
        idFilterJS = getRadioValue();
        var url = "applyfilter?action=applyfilterXML&id=" + idFilterJS;
        req = initRequest();
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.onreadystatechange = applyFilterCallBack;
        req.send(null);
    }
```

Next, I had a breakpoint in ApplyFilterServlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        session = request.getSession();
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
}
```

I have two questions:

1. What does MonitorRequestWraper mean for request variable during debug mode?
2. "request.getParameter("action");" returns null. Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It extends the request.  Dig down into the attributes under "inherited" to find your attributes.
public class MonitorRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper

Comment: add suggestions in comment